# Stick struct objects in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, struct

I got a new questions about **struct objects**:

I have 2 structs, one is called **"B1"**, and the other one is **"B2"**, both have similar fields but aren't the same.

Now, I want to stick both struct objects keeping their fields, actually if one of them have the same field (that could happen), overwrite it.

I tried with **cat** command, and that just gave me this:

```
K>> cat(1,B1,B2)

ans = 

2x1 struct array with fields:
    meandata
```

As you can see, **"cat"** created an object with 2 structs, and I want to make something like I show you in the next example:

First of all:

```
A.A1.A2=1;
A.A2.A2='a';

B1=A;
```

Finally:

```
A.A1.A2=3;
A.A2.CC='b';

B2=A;
```

Now, I want to make this:

```
[B]=StickStructFunction(B1,B2)
```

Option 1: ('OverWrite')

```
B=
    A.A1.A2=3;%=> Overwrite if the field exist already.
    A.A2.A2='a';
    A.A2.CC='b';
```

Option 2: ('Keep the values')

```
B=
    A.A1.A2=[1 3];%=> Keep the values if the field exist already.
    A.A2.A2='a';
    A.A2.CC='b';
```

I'll really appreciate any kind of help, thanks!

Comment: I think you mean you want to _merge_ the two structs, right?

Comment: take a look at this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7842-catstruct  and this http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34054-merge-structures/content/MergeStruct.m

Comment: Yes @Floris, you're right!

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how to do this. Creating two structs, A and B, you find all the fields in B - then you create a new struct C (a copy of A) and write all the valid B fields in it. When the field exists, it is overwritten; when it does not, it is created.

```
A.a = 1;
A.b = 2;
A.c = 3;
B.b = 4;
B.d = 6;

f2 = fieldnames(B);
C = A;
for ii = 1:numel(f2)
    C.(f2{ii}) = B.(f2{ii});
end

disp(C)
```

Result:

```
C
a: 1
b: 4
c: 3
d: 6
```